# How to return two types of objects in an ASP.net MVC view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have say class/ojbect one which I am returning as details. But then there is a second class that is related to the first that I want to list (and have an option to look at the details). How do I get return both of those?

Example is like in an item as the main piece but there may be details or other items that are related to the main item. I will select them with a linq query but then how do I return them to the same view?

Do I need to have some sort of partial or other form to display the second object type?
I don't see where returning the view I can return both.

My thought for right now is to create a new class that contains both of the object types but I know there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
My thought for right now is to create a new class that contains both of the object types but I know there has to be a better way.
```

That is the right way. Create a **ViewModel** class that contains all the data that view needs and pass it to view.

Comment: Can we agree to call it the 'current architecturally acceptable' way?  While this technique will work, I find it terribly unmaintainable.

Comment: @Jeff - OK ;-) - I've been using this technique for some time now (*all* my views use view models) and I haven't noticed much maintenance pain. on the contrary, it's easier to see what data the view requires, as it's in one place. Not to mention the benefits of type-safety.

Comment: The maintenance issue I have with the ViewModel - Model technique stems from the need to create 2 models for every screen that is created

Comment: @Jeff - ? what 2 models? Are you talking about 'entity edit' view where you use 2 classes for view model & entity model? Not all views look like that. Some do not have entity model, others use more than 2 classes...

Answer (score 1):

You can either pass it to View through **ViewState** or **ViewBag**  (depending on which MVC version you are using).

Answer (score 0):

for the first object "main object" return it as the model of this view and for the details 
put them into ViewState and cast them back within the view